# Liquidsoap + mpeg4 audio how?

Tags: audio, mp4, icecast, liquidsoap

How to create an audio stream using mpeg4 liquidsoap + icecast?
We do not want to use a third-party utility such as ffmpeg, can we do it only on liquidsoap?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquidsoap can play mp4 as long as you have the appropriate libraries compiled in your liquidsoap installation.

The library you probably want is ocaml-faad.

If its not in your liquidsoap installation you can compile liquidsoap from source. Be sure that `ocaml-faad` is uncommented in the PACKAGES file.
https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap-full/blob/master/PACKAGES.default#L93

You can try playing a static playlist of mpeg4 files:
http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/reference.html#playlist

or a single file:
http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/reference.html#single

Hope that helps!